# using flatmap to separate array with comma

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```js
[
  ["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
  ["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
  ["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
]
```

I need this:

```js
[
  ["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
  ["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"],
  ["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
  ["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
]
```

Here's my code:

```js
const source = [ 
  ["Polymeric", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
  ["Cast", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
  ["Polymeric", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
];


source.flatMap(([key, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10, value11, value12, value13, value14, value15, value16]) => { 

  const values = value16.split(', ') 

  var hjk = values.map(singleValue => [key, singleValue])
  console.log(hjk);
})
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7gorq6t/23/) of it working.

Is there a better way to do this? Putting value1, value2 etc seems silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could destructure the wanted values and map the wanted pairs.

```js
const
    source = [["Polymeric", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"], ["Cast", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"], ["Polymeric", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]],
    result = source.flatMap(({ 0: key, 16: values }) => values
        .split(', ')
        .map(value => [key, value])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
const source = [ 
  ["Polymeric", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
  ["Cast", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
  ["Polymeric", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
];


source.flatMap((arr) => { 
  let [key] = arr;
  let value16 = arr[16];
  const values = value16.split(', ') 

  var hjk = values.map(singleValue => [key, singleValue])
  console.log(hjk);
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly but chose the first answer because it was done in less lines. Thank you